# How to find previous .multiselect class of li using active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of select box suppose `.multiselect` is parent of all elements under it (i.e. `<li>`) when user select one option `.active` class is added to it.

```js
$(".multiselect-container.dropdown-menu li").each(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("active")){
         var TypeSubId = $(this).find("input").val();
         var TypeID =  $(this).prev(".multiselect").find("input").val();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li class="multiselect"><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li class="active"><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li class="multiselect"><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li class="active"><input type="checkbox" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
</ul>
```

So Now I need help in finding `TypeID`(value in JS code). I want to find value of `input checkbox` of first `.multiselect` above `.active`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to find multi Select

```
  $(this).prevAll("li.multiselect:first").find("input").val()
```